# How can I tell the difference between photos that exist only online and those where the Google Photos-synced original is still on my phone?

Tags: google-photos, synchronization

## Background

On my phone I have Google Photos configured to sync my photos to the cloud.

Periodically Google Photos prompts me to delete photos from my phone in order to free up space, and I choose the option that only deletes the original from my phone.

In this way, space is freed up on my phone, but the synced cloud-based copy is not deleted and can still be accessed from the web app.

## Question

When using the Google Photos web app, is there an easy way to differentiate between synced photos that exist only online versus those where the originals still exist on my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. In order sync to work, Google Photos has access to your gallery and camera on your device, and your device has granted access for uploading to Google Photos. And here it ends. Your device has no means to backcheck against the online gallery and let you know which ones are there and which aren't. Also the same applies to Google Photos - it doesn't backcheck against your device gallery and send you a notification flag of the status nor it keeps/creates logs by spying on your device's gallery.